# Como esconder o botão next e previous no último e primeiro conteúdo do Carousel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Estou usando um Carousel com Bootstrap, mas eu preciso que o botão *next* suma quando chegar o ultimo item e que o botão *previous* fique escondido enquanto estiver no primeiro conteúdo.

O meu código não está funcionando, mas não identifico o problema, então vou colocar abaixo.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <img src="img/ft-carousel-home.jpg" width="430" height="308">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <div class="control">
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">previous</a>              
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">next</a>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Estudo revela percepções sobre o cultivo da cana 1</h3>
                    <p>Avaliar sob a ótica de moradores locais os efeitos ambientais, econômicos e sociais após dez anos da chegada da cultura</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Estudo revela percepções sobre o cultivo da cana 2</h3>
                    <p>Avaliar sob a ótica de moradores locais os efeitos ambientais, econômicos e sociais após dez anos da chegada da cultura</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Estudo revela percepções sobre o cultivo da cana 1</h3>
                    <p>Avaliar sob a ótica de moradores locais os efeitos ambientais, econômicos e sociais após dez anos da chegada da cultura</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $('#slider').carousel({
        interval: false,
    })
    
    $(document).ready(function () {               // on document ready
        checkitem();
    });
    
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkitem);
    
    function checkitem()                        // check function
    {
        var $this = $('#myCarousel');
        if ($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
            // Hide left arrow
            $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
            // But show right arrow
            $this.children('.right.carousel-control').show();
        } else if ($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
            // Hide right arrow
            $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
            // But show left arrow
            $this.children('.left.carousel-control').show();
        } else {
            $this.children('.carousel-control').show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A estrutura do seu Carousel está incorreta. O Carousel só irá funcionar se tiver a estrutura conforme informada na **[documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)**.

Alguns seletores estão incorretos também, outros faltando etc.. se for listar aqui tudo, vai ficar enorme. Melhor ver no código abaixo corrigido e comparar com o seu código.

Ajustei também o JavaScript para pegar os elementos certinho escondendo/mostrando as setas conforme deseja:

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
     interval: false,
 })

 $(document).ready(function () {               // on document ready
     checkitem();
 });

 $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkitem);

 function checkitem()                        // check function
 {
     var $this = $('#myCarousel');
     if ($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first').hasClass('active')) {
         // Hide left arrow
         $('.carousel-control-prev', $this).hide();
         // But show right arrow
         $('.carousel-control-next', $this).show();
     } else if ($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:last').hasClass('active')) {
         // Hide right arrow
         $('.carousel-control-prev', $this).show();
         // But show left arrow
         $('.carousel-control-next', $this).hide();
     } else {
         $('.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next', $this).show();
     }
 }
```

```css
img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
     <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="430" height="308">
       <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h3>Estudo revela percepções sobre o cultivo da cana 1</h3>
                 <p>Avaliar sob a ótica de moradores locais os efeitos ambientais, econômicos e sociais após dez anos da chegada da cultura</p>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="430" height="308">
       <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h3>Estudo revela percepções sobre o cultivo da cana 2</h3>
                 <p>Avaliar sob a ótica de moradores locais os efeitos ambientais, econômicos e sociais após dez anos da chegada da cultura</p>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="430" height="308">
       <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h3>Estudo revela percepções sobre o cultivo da cana 1</h3>
                 <p>Avaliar sob a ótica de moradores locais os efeitos ambientais, econômicos e sociais após dez anos da chegada da cultura</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
 <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
 <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, aqui funcionou, mas eu tive que modificar muito o css pra funcionar com o layout do site que eu estou fazendo, recomendo para alguém que ver este artigo, usar o css sem linkar e deletar tudo inútil que o bootstrap trás pois prejudica muito o projeto no quesito herança.

Comment: Pois eh, por isso não uso o BS.

Comment: então mas foi o único no qual eu encontrei esse código para o meu objetivo, eu não manjo muito a fundo javascript pra criar um do zero, senão nem seria necessário recorrer ao bootstrap

Comment: Vc quer fazer apenas 1 slider? Tem mt plugin JS pra isso, nem precisa do BS.

Comment: Sim, no caso deste site que estou fazendo apenas este carousel terá este sistema, eu pequisei mtos sites e documentações e a única que encontrei foi em bootstrap se vc tiver outra agradeço grandemente